# What Should be the Permissions of Apache SSL Directory, Certificate, and Key?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, permissions, ssl, file-permissions

I have my `cert.pem` and `cert.key` files in `/etc/apache2/ssl` folders.

What would be the most secure permissions and ownership of:

1. `/etc/apache2/ssl` directory
2. `/etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem` file
3. `/etc/apache2/ssl/cert.key` file

(Ensuring `https://` access works of course :).

Thanks,

JP

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The directory permissions should be 700, the file permissions on all the files should be 600, and the directory and files should be owned by root.

Comment: Thanks. This works. One thing - I guess the files only need to be read by root that starts the apache daemon. Why do we need to give "write" permissions to the file?

Comment: The files will need updating periodically, as your certificates expire and need to be renewed, and since there's no real security risk in making them writeable it makes life slightly simpler. They don't need to be readable for day-to-day use, so you can use 400 permissions (and 500 on the directory) if you don't mind having to fiddle with them at renewal time.

Comment: It should be noted, that the official Apache Docs  do not agree with Mike's original suggestions about SSL and go with his second suggestion here in the comments.

Comment: What should the owner be?

Comment: where did you find the "official Apache Docs" about ssl

Comment: Its mentioned one time here in the SSL faq. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_faq.html#removepassphrase

Answer (score 0):

**The most important is to make sure the `*.key` files are only readable by `root`** ([SSL/TLS Strong Encryption: FAQ](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_faq.html#removepassphrase)).

My experience is that it could be realized also to other files of the certificates (like `*.crt` for example).

So we should set the `root` as the only one owner of the directory and its files:

```
$ chown -R root:root /etc/apache2/ssl
```

And we can set the most restrictive permissions for this localization:

```
$ chmod -R 000 /etc/apache2/ssl
```

In some particular case, the localization can be different of course.