# What permissions should I give to CA Bundle file?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

Hi I setup an ssl certificate using godaddy and read the following article: [Best location for SSL certificate and private keys on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/259302/best-location-for-ssl-certificate-and-private-keys-on-ubuntu). I am trying to protect an aws ubuntu gitlab instance that uses nginx as a server.

My /etc/ssl/private/ has the following files:

```
.csr generated on server
.key generated on server
.crt generated by godaddy
.crt BUNDLE generated by godaddy
```

I have given them the following permissions respectively:

```
root:root 644
root:ssl-cert 640
root:root 644
root:root 644
```

Is this correct?

It has been mentioned that this question is the same as [What Should be the Permissions of Apache SSL Directory, Certificate, and Key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/216477/what-should-be-the-permissions-of-apache-ssl-directory-certificate-and-key) and my only reason that it is distinct is because it is for nginx NOT apache.

Comment: but this is for nginx not apache

Comment: There's no difference in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is distinct from [What Should be the Permissions of Apache SSL Directory, Certificate, and Key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/216477/what-should-be-the-permissions-of-apache-ssl-directory-certificate-and-key) because it is for nginx.

However, following https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md helped me and the answer turned out to be the same as the answer to the apache question [What Should be the Permissions of Apache SSL Directory, Certificate, and Key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/216477/what-should-be-the-permissions-of-apache-ssl-directory-certificate-and-key).

Specifically, I followed the "Enable HTTPS" section which said to do:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/gitlab/ssl
sudo chmod 700 /etc/gitlab/ssl
sudo cp gitlab.example.com.key gitlab.example.com.crt /etc/gitlab/ssl/
sudo ufw allow https
```

I also made root the owner of the /etc/gitlab/ssl directory and the .crt and .key files inside it, and made the .crt and the .key files' permissions 600, just like the apache answer says.

I don't mind if this question is deleted but first the Apache question's title should be changed to "What Should be the Permissions of Apache/Nginx SSL Directory, Certificate, and Key?"